# Styling Custom Dialogs

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way, specifically in android studio, to see what one's custom dialog would look like without actually running the application? It seems that the Design view of layouts account only for entire-screen designs. It also seems that sometimes the way the "dialog" looks in the design view is wildly different than the way they look live.

I would share some of my code, I know you guys love that, but this isn't exactly a coding question, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third party tools and mirrors. I think the closest you can get is by checking [this](http://www.jimumirror.com) out.

This is `hot swapping` in general and you get interactive previews but like I said it is the closest you can get. I haven't worked thoroughly with it but I think this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: that actually looks awesome. I was hoping Android Studio could do something like this natively, but this is definitely the way I'll go.

Comment: I don't think that Android Studio provides native support, as of now, for what you have asked.

Comment: thats alright. ill check mirror out. see what it can do. on the surface it seems like exactly what i want.